# In Windows service how to INSERT records into database from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have a windows service which has five threads.Each thread will pic different Excel file then it reads the excel rows and inserting into data base. Is it possible to INSERT parallelly ? Currently i am using single class with **lock** for inserting.

Comment: following is my code, since i am usig lock each thead will wait till the another thead completes its INSERT operation. I want to avoid thread waiting and want to INSERT parallally. Give a solution where each thread can INSERT independently.

Comment: public void WriteToServer(DataTable dataTable, OracleBulkCopyOptions options, IEnumerable<OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping> columnMappings)
        {
            lock (writeLock)
            {
                using (var bulkcopy = new OracleBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;
                    foreach (var mapping in columnMappings)
                        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping);
                    bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = TimeOut.Value;
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

Comment: Could you please edit your question so the code resides *in* the question, and then delete the two comments holding the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting and the key is created for you by the DBMS, then there should be no problem, and no need to lock.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your database. If you database is capable of handling multiple connections (which it should nowaways).

It has nothing to do with your class where you do the insert though. Any locking there is not really necessary (unless, of course, you database does not support multiple connections, which I seriously doubt).

Comment: following is my code, since i am usig lock each thead will wait till the another thead completes its INSERT operation. I want to avoid thread waiting and want to INSERT parallally. Give a solution where each thread can INSERT independently.

Comment: public void WriteToServer(DataTable dataTable, OracleBulkCopyOptions options, IEnumerable<OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping> columnMappings)
        {
            lock (writeLock)
            {
                using (var bulkcopy = new OracleBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;
                    foreach (var mapping in columnMappings)
                        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping);
                    bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = TimeOut.Value;
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's in a transaction, and get rid of the lock! You should be fine...assuming whatever database you're using supports transactions.

Most modern databases will support multiple writes, it's safer to use the transaction incase another goes wrong.